# Tensorflow variable sharing between instances of class

Tags: tensorflow

```
class E():
    def __init__(self):
        self.sess = tf.Session()
        xav_init = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer
        self.b_Wi = tf.get_variable(name='b_Wi', shape=[2,3], dtype=tf.float32,  initializer=xav_init())
e = E()
e1 = E()
```

Getting below error when executing above code.

```
ValueError: Variable b_Wi already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True or reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope? Originally defined at:
```

I know their are workarounds, but i am more trying to unserstand the logic behind above. Isn't instances should have their own separate variables.
Why are they shared b/w e and e1 above ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from itertools import count
import tensorflow as tf

class E():
    _ids = count(0)
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = next(self._ids)
        self.sess = tf.Session()
        xav_init = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer
        with tf.variable_scope("share") as sp:
            print(self.id)
            if self.id > 0:
                tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
            self.b_Wi = tf.get_variable(name='b_Wi', shape=[2,3], dtype=tf.float32,  initializer=xav_init())

e1 = E()
e2 = E()

assert(e1.b_Wi == e2.b_Wi) # thus they are exactly the same object in the same graph and hence affect each other.
```

Comment: Thanks, Not sure if .reuse_variables() will have any effect on e1 weights  when e2 is called. But yeah exception is not their.

Comment: @duck It will, since they are in a common (default) graph.

Comment: Thanks what i mean was, are these variable independent, or chnageing the variable from one instance will affect other as well

Comment: Thanks for the info @lerner